# Good name for a geometrical function

Tags: geometry

There is a function of a 2D geometrical shape and 1D interval,

> f(s, i) = P<sub>y</sub> (s ⋂ i×(-∞,∞))

It calculates intersection of shape with infinite vertical rectangle (determined by given interval `i = [x1, x2)`) and then projects it to Y axis.

Is there a good name for this function?

Comment: For Java implementation: CalculateIntersectionOfShapeWithInfiniteVerticalRectangleDeterminedByInterval(shape,interval).
FORTRAN implementation: CIOSWIVRDBI(S,I) or if that is too long: ISR(S, I) :-p

Comment: @NealB, almost +1, the first letter for the Java name should be lower case :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics rather than programming.

Answer (score 3):

`GetIntersection` seems like an obvious candidate...

Comment: Well, that's not only intersection. I was hoping that there is a well-known geometrical operator which acts like this function, so I can use its name.

Comment: @user713303, my thinking is, name the function at least in the ballpark and then thoroughly comment it its the header (in whatever way your language of choice does that). Function names are easy to refactor if months down the line you think of a better one.

Comment: it's already been named yProjection, so it's already about renaming

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like Blindy's answer maybe you can call it:

```
ProjectoToYAfterIntersectingInfiniteRectangle(x1,x2)
```

But I would go with just `GetIntersection` as Blindy said +1